# How to make EditText not clickable and hide keyboard but show cursor using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a custom keyboard. I want my `EditText` to show the cursor blinking but when the user would click on the `EditText`, the standard default should not show up. `android:clickable="false"` doesn't work.

When I use `android:focusable="false"`, I only see the cursor when I click the `EditText`. When I put `android:inputType="none"` I can still click the `EditText` and the default keyboard shows.

When I use `android:enabled="false"` it's not clickable and also the cursor is not shown anymore.

```
editText.requestFocus()


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="false" />
```